# ChildrenAsTriggers updatePanel not updating after Database Save

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, web-parts

Greetings,

I have a page that loads `userEvents` (Ie a wall post or profile update) in a webpart, this webpart is then registered onto a comment page, so then the person adds a wall comment we need to update the `updatepanel` that holds the web part. We cannot add the `textbox` and `button` to the webpart as it is a "reader" that issued on other parts of the site. So when the person adds a wall post it saves to the DB and loads a `UserEvent` into a different section to the DB, after this has happened to need to update the `UpadatePanel` holding the `UserEvent` Reader webpart. Ive read up and I think our solution is to use `ChildrenAsTriggers`.

Your help will be appreciated.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddWallPost" CssClass="multilinetextbox" MaxLength="200" runat="server"
                         TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                          <br /> 
                        <div class="buttons">
 <asp:Button ID="btnButtonWallPost" runat="server" OnClick="btnButtonWallPost_Click">
                        </asp:Button>
                        </div>         
                        </div>

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                <uc1:UserEventsWebPart ID="UserEventsWebPart1" runat="server"  />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I hope I made this clear enough :P

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, when a user hits the "btnButtonWallPost" button, you want the content within UpdatePanel1 to be updated?

If I do understand you correctly, then I'm a little confused by your set up. Why do you need the inner UpdatePanel? Everything should be updated when the button is clicked. That'll cause an update of the outer UpdatePanel which will in turn, update the inner UpdatePanel.

And yes, I believe setting ChildrenAsTriggers on the outer UpdatePanel should do the trick (although I believe it's set to true by default anyway).

Comment: Thanks, This was just the latest version of the aspc code. Basically everything works exept it is not displaying the NEW data that was just posted ( The New Wall Post) ive added a button that does nothing, the click event is blank in the code behind, but when I click it it updates that info. So im guessing it has to do with view state or some postback something.

Comment: if you look at Facebook, as soon as you hit the return they, what you types displays immediatly on the WALL...we are looking at getting that result.